# Call view script of (parent) Abstract controller Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a parent (abstract) controller, I have 2 child controllers extending the abstract controller. I have an action which is common in both the child controllers, hence I implemented in my abstract controller.

The problem is when I call this action from one of the child controllers (e.g. /module/child1/commonaction), the action call pass through to the base controller and after executing the functionality, it looks for the view script. I have a common view script under the folder name same as that of base controller, but underlying Zend mechanism looks for the view script in the directory named after the child controller (in this case it looks for child1/commonaction.phtml) though I have the view script in basecontroller/commonaction.phtml.

how can I render the view script under the base controller directory?

Comment: You should specify the version of the framework that you're using. Having both tags is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way it to probably within your action disable the default viewRenderer and Render the file yourself.

```
// coerce a view from the view renderer.
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->initView("/path/to/base/controller");
$this->view = $viewRenderer->view;
// disable automatic rendering
$viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
// do all your action stuff here
$this->getResponse()->appendBody($this->view->render("viewscript.phtml");
```

Comment: Note the answer you give is based on ZF1, the question is also tagged with ZF2. Not sure what version @Obaid uses though..